# Your instant app APKs do not declare at least one web 'intent-filter' element with the attribute 'android:autoVerify' set to true

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm getting this error message when uploading an AAB to google play console.

> Your instant app APKs do not declare at least one web 'intent-filter'
> element with the attribute 'android:autoVerify' set to true in the
> Android manifest.

should i declare it inside the intent-filter or main application itself?

and what is it for?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#request-verify

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity ...>

<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

[Request app links verification][1]